# iPhone Developer License

Tags: iphone

I wanted to know if we have a iPhone Developer Enterprise License, then is it possible to distribute our apps to a limited number of users (of our choice) through App Store? In other words, we would like our iPhone apps to be visible to a limited number of users (whom we have selected to preview our apps)

Also, is there any other way to distribute our apps other than the App Store?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an `iOS Developer Enterprise Licence` you will be able to distribute your apps to a limited number of users but **not through the AppStore**, in fact the apps in the AppStore are available to every user. You will be able to **sign and distribute** (via Wi-Fi or 3G) your own apps to make them run **only** on selected devices, though. This is called `In-House Distribution`.

Comment: thanks. but how will i distribute my signed apps and how will my intended audience download them to their iPhone device?

Comment: also if we have an enterprise license ($299), is it limited to a particular number of developers or applicable to all developers in the company?

Comment: You can sign and share your app using XCode. It's easy!. When you think your app is ready select “Build and Archive” from your XCode build menu, by doing this your app will be stored in the “Archived Applications” section of the XCode organizer (Window > Organizer). Now select the app you want to share and select “Share Application…”, pick the appropriate provisioning profile and then “Distribute for Enterprise”. In the distribution window, enter the title and the full url to the ipa file, for example: http://testurl.com/example.ipa

Comment: You can find more infos here! http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 2):

With an enterprise license you can't distribute your app on the App store. Actually you wouldn't even get the access to iTunesConnect. The only way to distribute your app is by ad-hoc or in-house distribution.

Comment: The Enterprise license is only for companies with a DUNS number. (remove the 'with 500 or more employes and you must have') see comment below.

Comment: Actually Apple has recently lifted the 500 employees bar.

Answer (score 0):

No, apps on the app-store are visible to all users. Depending on the device they are then downloadable.

But you can distribute you app to a limited number of users via ad hoc distribution. Therefore you need to know the device ids of the devices the app should run on.

Comment: Thanks to everybody for the brilliant answers. Love stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do so through the Apple App store, but you can - with the enterprise license - distribute apps directly to people whom you authorise.  This means that yes you can host the app at a URL that you control and can therefore limit access to however you wish to.  Users will need a provisioning profile - but this isn't created using your 100 device limit from Apple.

The Apple Guide is at http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/Enterprise_Deployment_Guide.pdf - see chapter 5 in particular.

This covers the mechanic of doing what you want.  I'd take a close look at the t's and c's of the Enterprise Programme as the programme is clearly intended to allow organisations to distribute within the organisation - not as a means to bypass the app store.  I hope your target users are within your organisation.

Comment: Yes, my target users are within my organization. Regarding the apple guide PDF mentioned in your above post, I am unable to understand the section called - "Disabling an Enterprise Application" in page-66. My question is how do we "Revoke" the identity? I mean we would have already got the UDID from our targetted users and accordingly provided them the provisioning file. So the provisioning file is already present in thier respective devices. So how do we revoke it from our end? Hope I was able to express my query clearly? Again thanks for your time and help.